# Making Stacked Objects Seamless

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

I made a quick illustration to demonstrate my problem. In this first picture I have 5 stacked objects; the upper and lower lip, the surfboard and two sets of teeth.

[image]

I want the bottom teeth to overlap the surfboard. But when I move it up the stack, this happens.

[image]

Any tips on how I would make the teeth and the lips seamless without giving up the positioning?

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

**Clipping Mask**

- Using the **Direct Selection Tool** > select the central path of the inner part of the lower mouth shape
- **Menu Edit** > **Copy**
- **Menu Edit** > **Paste in Front**
- Close the shape and selecting it together with the teeth group, go to **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Make**

[image: Clipping Mask]

**Shape Builder**

- Select the bottom mouth shape and the teeth group
- Using the **Shape Builder Tool** and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete, click on each tooth segment inside the mouth.

[image: builder]